# Multiple flights with low cost airlines

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, low-cost-carriers, ryanair, easyjet

I want to travel with Ryainair and/or Easyjet from my hometown to a destination that those companies do serve but not directly from my hometown. Is there a site that can help with these kind of requests (to match arrival and departure hours of different flights of the same airline)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Low-cost airline transfers are *non-protected* even if you fly with the same airline on both legs, which is why they typically won't show up in a search. Not only that, you will have to book each leg separately (again, even if they're with the same low-cost airline).

If you search with SkyScanner, tick the option "Non-protected transfers" under "Multi-part booking". This is not checked by default.

[image: SkyScanner "Non-protected transfers" option]

I'm not sure where to find this option on other engines or if it even exists.

Comment: And to clarify what "non-protected" means: if your flight in on Easyjet is delayed and you miss your connection to Ryanair, you're screwed.  You'll need to buy a new ticket, and the next flight might be a week away.  So allow as much extra time for the connection as you possibly can.